# Quiero realizar un salto en el que mientras mas presiones mas salte el personaje.Unity 2d

Tags: unity2d

Estoy haciendo un juego de plataformas 2D,tengo un salto básico implementado usando las física de rigidbody2d,en el que si presionas una vez la tecla se eleva hacia arriba.La idea es que al segun que tanto presiones,es lo mucho que va a saltar el personaje.Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Implementa `IKeyboarEvent` interface y sus métodos

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour, IKeyboardEvent
{
    private float tiempoInicio;
    private float tiempo;

    public void OnKey(KeyCode keycode)
    {
        tiempoInicio = Time.time;
    }

    public void OnKeyDown(KeyCode keycode)
    {
        //
    }

    public void OnKeyUP(KeyCode keycode)
    {
        tiempo = Time.time - tiempoInicio;
        //este es el tiempo que lleva la tecla presionada
        Debug.Log("tiempo presionado " + tiempo);
    }
}
```

Con este dato del tiempo que lleva presionada la tecla podrás utilizarlo para influir en el valor del movimiento. 
Saludos

Comment: Gracias!,pero como utilizo el interface IkeyboardEvent?,estoy en la versión 2018.3 y al parecer debo usar: usingEngine.Experimental.UiElement.KeyboardEvent; pero no funciona!,saludos